# Add entire xml node to an element using lxml

Tags: python-2.7, lxml

I am trying to add new nodes to an element tree. These new nodes have childs in them. Is there anyway using lxml to add all these in one go.

Ex: 
**Old format**

```
<Test>
    <Header>
    </Header>
</Test>
```

**New format that I am trying to achieve by adding nodes**

```
<Test>
    <Header>
        <Source>
           <ProcessID> 234 </ProcessID>
           <InstanceID> 1 </InstanceID>
        </Source>  
        <Target>
           <ProcessID> 234 </ProcessID>
           <InstanceID> 1 </InstanceID>
        </Target>
     </Header>
</Test>
```

I am looking for 2 things:

1) Is there anyway by which I can add entire Source node and Target node in one go? I mean adding source node in one go and Target node in one go. Instead of adding source node and then processID and then InstanceID etc

2) At the moment I am maintaining changes in a flat file and storing the changes and then applying them using lxml

The problem I am facing is, 
When I add Source node to Header node using Subelement it is not added as proper tag and only closure tag of Source is added. When I try to get Source element using **find** function I am getting element as null. Hence I can't add childs to Source node. As you can see Source node doesn't have any attributes or text, but it has childs.
Can you help me in adding this structure to element tree? I tried all the ways as much as I can. I am sure there should be a simple solution to do this instead of adding it one by one.
I have so many files to be treated like this, so looking for a simple solution.

TIA

Comment: No one is there to help me out :(

Comment: Add the code you tried